# Ubuntu 22.04 Sierra EM7455 no GPS/NMEA data over /dev/ttyUSB1

Tags: gps

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 370. It contains a LTE with GPS card from Sierra EM7455. I re-configured the EM7455 card to provide a serial GPS/NMEA output. It wokrs just fine if I use Windows 10. The com-Port outputs gps data.

Unluckily, this is not the case in Ubuntu 22.04.

(Neither in /dev/ttyUSB0, nor /dev/ttyUSB1, nor /dev/ttyUSB2 (which is the modem-configuration in/out that works just fine)

I kindly ask you for support on how I can get GPS/NMEA-Data output on
/dev/ttyUSB1

A connection to the modem to send at-commands back and forth on /dev/ttyUSB2 works just fine. (I use the command $ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB2 for the communication.

Here is some information about my setup.

```
sudo apt remove gpsd
sudo apt remove gpsd-clients
sudo apt remove modem-manager-gui
systemctl stop ModemManager
```

(aim was to exclude all iterferences from other processes to have the native GPS-data visible on /dev/ttyUSB1)

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:5682 IMC Networks SunplusIT Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. EM7455
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:509c Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo dmesg | grep ttyUSB
[    8.850698] usb 1-2: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    8.851173] usb 1-2: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    8.942523] usb 1-2: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 1383.674395] audit: type=1400 audit(1659010167.409:228): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/run/udev/data/+usb-serial:ttyUSB1" pid=5750 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1383.674803] audit: type=1400 audit(1659010167.409:229): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/run/udev/data/+usb-serial:ttyUSB2" pid=5750 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 1383.675219] audit: type=1400 audit(1659010167.409:230): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/run/udev/data/+usb-serial:ttyUSB0" pid=5750 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qcserial, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 10, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qmi_wwan, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qcserial, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qcserial, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 8, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qmi_wwan, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Info about the Modem:

It is set to provide serial output of GPS/NMEA-Data.
It starts automatically with transmission of ASCII-GPS-Data
(receiveable in Windows 10, but not when booted with Ubuntu 22.04)

My problem is, that this GPS-Data is not available on
/dev/ttyUSB1 (or /dev/ttyUSB0 if atall)

Here is the modem respons that shows how I configured it ( /dev/ttyUSB2 ):

```
ati3
Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
Model: EM7455
Revision: SWI9X30C_02.38.00.00 rE3F3E55C03AE94 jenkins 2022/01/13 05:16:00
MEID: 01458200734481
IMEI: 014582007344816
IMEI SV: 22
FSN: LF725373650210
+GCAP: +CGSM

at!usbcomp?
Config Index: 1
Config Type:  1 (Generic)
Interface bitmask: 0000050D (diag,nmea,modem,rmnet0,rmnet1) 

at!gpsautostart?
  function:  1
  fixtype: 1
  maxtime: 180 seconds
  maxdist: 100 meters
  fixrate: 1 seconds
```

Any help higly appreciated.

Best Regards

Hartmut